# terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException, when I run my code for my camera

Tags: swift, camera

When I try to run my camera I get an error message that says following

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException and "Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported"

I have been watching for solutions on stackOverflow but haven't been succesful.

Tried to redirect my outlet my I can't understand where the problem occurs. Therefor I tried to put some breakpoint to find it but didn't manage

```
let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer:CALayer!

    var captureDevice:AVCaptureDevice!

    var takePhoto = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        prepareCamera()
    }

    func prepareCamera() {
        captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

        let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: AVMediaType.video, position: .back).devices
        captureDevice = availableDevices.first
        beginSession()

    }

    func beginSession () {
        do {
            let captureDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

            captureSession.addInput(captureDeviceInput)

        }catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }


        let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        self.previewLayer = previewLayer
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
        self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.frame
        captureSession.startRunning()

        let dataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        dataOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString):NSNumber(value:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String : Any]

        dataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(dataOutput) {
            captureSession.addOutput(dataOutput)
        }

        captureSession.commitConfiguration()

        let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.brianadvent.captureQueue")
        dataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: queue)
    }

    @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: Any) {
        takePhoto = true
    }

    func captureOutput(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer!, from connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

        if takePhoto {
            takePhoto = false

            if let image = self.getImageFromSampleBuffer(buffer: sampleBuffer) {

                let photoVC =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:  nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PhotoVC") as! Viewcontroller2

                photoVC.takenPhoto = image

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.present(photoVC, animated: true, completion: {
                        self.stopCaptureSession()
                    })

                }
            }
        }
    }

    func getImageFromSampleBuffer (buffer:CMSampleBuffer) -> UIImage? {
        if let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(buffer) {
            let ciImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer)
            let context = CIContext()

            let imageRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pixelBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(pixelBuffer))

            if let image = context.createCGImage(ciImage, from: imageRect) {
                return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .right)
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func stopCaptureSession () {
        self.captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let inputs = captureSession.inputs as? [AVCaptureDeviceInput] {
            for input in inputs {
                self.captureSession.removeInput(input)
            }
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    struct Constants {
        static let apiKey = "AIzaSyDtaJ5eU24rbnHsG9pb1STOizDJvqcaj5E"
        static let bundleId = "com.felibundle"
        static let searchEngineId = "016628067786358079133:2gm9usqzouc"
    }
    @IBAction func pish(_ sender: Any) {
        googleSearch(term: "George Bush") { results in
            print(results)}
    }
    func googleSearch(term: String, callback:@escaping ([(title: String, url: String)]?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = String(format: "https://cse.google.com/cse?cx=016628067786358079133:2gm9usqzouc", term, Constants.searchEngineId, Constants.apiKey)
        let encodedUrl = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)

        guard let url = URL(string: encodedUrl ?? urlString) else {
            print("invalid url \(urlString)")
            return
        }

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue(Constants.bundleId, forHTTPHeaderField: "X-Ios-Bundle-Identifier")

        let session = URLSession.shared
        let datatask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
            guard
                error == nil,
                let data = data,
                let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : Any]
                else {

                    callback(nil)
                    return
            }

            guard let items = json?["items"] as? [[String : Any]], items.count > 0 else {
                print("no results")
                return
            }

            callback(items.map { ($0["title"] as! String, $0["formattedUrl"] as! String) })
        }
        datatask.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Post full error text here.

Comment: 00 testing2[514:31963] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2019-05-09 23:15:48.446844+0200 testing2[514:31963] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession addInput:] Multiple audio/video AVCaptureInputs are not currently supported'
*** First throw call stack:
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb) @SharadChauhan

Answer (score 0):

Your code runs fine at my end.
However, this kind of error arrives when we try to add multiple `input` device to the same `session`. Make sure you are not adding `AVCaptureInputs` object elsewhere in your project

Comment: I have solved that now but can't capture a picture from my first viewcontroller to my second instead I get two camera views in each view controller @Akash Bhardwaj

Comment: If your are getting two camera views, that means your have added the 'preview layer' multiple times.

Comment: Okey but I would like one of them to become the view where I display my image in my image view instead. Can you see where the problem is. @Akash Bhardwaj

Comment: I don't think you're able to capture any image with the above posted code. Since your post is totally differs to what you are asking now, I would suggest you to ask the different in a new post. For now, I can hint you that you're using wrong/depreciated delegate method and the way of capturing  the image is also not appropriate. Try to go through some other tutorials.